# GPIO to control a 12V remote control

Tags: gpio, hardware, pi-3b+

I am trying to automate the pressing of a remote control button by the PI.

[image]

With the buzzer it works well.

If I replace the buzzer with the remote control it sort of works.

The remote control has an LED that shows when the button is pressed. The LED is always dimly lit. When I activate the transistor the LED pulses rather than stays on full.

If I bypass the transistor the LED comes on full as I would expect.

Here is a photo of my setup:

[image]

What should the circuit diagram look like?

Comment: This question appears to be identical to your earlier question. Do not post duplicates, edit your Question. You appear to have learned nothing from the earlier Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd add a comment but I don't have enough rep yet - We need to see the schematic of the remote you're trying to connect it to before we can answer.

Edit: Scratch that I think I see the issue:
Your circuit does not match your circuit diagram.
You've got pins 1 and 3 mixed up on your transistor.
You also do not seem to have connected the Pi and remote to a common ground as you have done in your diagram. If it is the green wire, then you need to connect it to pin 1 like it is on your diagram, right now it is connected to the negative supply of the battery after the remote, but your diagram grounds before the remote.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the schematics of the remote control. My idea was to just hard wire the button and control the power via the battery. This would activate when powered.

Comment: How much rep is needed to make a comment?

Comment: @Seamus 50 rep: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: Thank you @pokebab that fixed it.